# Can I have a broken down explanation of what is happening in each line of this C++ code?

Tags: c++, windows

I wanted to create a keylogger. I found a tutorial on it, and I coded it correctly, and it works. I understand basically all of the code, except for the stealth method:

```
void Stealth()
{

    HWND stealth;
    AllocConsole();
    stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(stealth,SW_HIDE);
}
```

if someone could give me a line by line break down of what is happening in this method, that would be absolutely amazing.

Comment: Yes, of course I've tried google. I've looked for each specific method and object and none of it was that much help. So of course, this is my last resort.

Comment: *" I must say I was ecstatic when I saw how similar the languages were."* - Don't be, because they're not.  Don't let syntactical similarities fool you, Java and C++ are vastly different languages.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it doesn't really answer your question. But a better alternative would be using the windows subsystem which wouldn't create a console window in the first place. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx

Comment: @Ed S, I will definitely keep that in mind. Thanks for the heads up. I feel like as I delve deeper into both languages this will become more apparent to me.

Comment: @LukaD Thanks! I'll definitely take a look at that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
HWND stealth;
```

declare a window handle.

```
AllocConsole();
```

Allocates a new console for the calling process.

```
stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
```

Find the window handle with class name "ConsoleWindowClass".

```
ShowWindow(stealth,SW_HIDE);
```

Hide it.

Comment: Wouldn't this hide every console window?

Comment: @LukaD `stealth` is the handle to the window named "ConsoleWindowClass". So no.

Comment: Thank you so much! this makes much more sense now!

Comment: @LukaD, if more than one console window is there, it will return the first one it finds.